# IdentityServer - separate authentification, authorization, resources without any use of UI-websites?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I want to have an architecture made up of these devices / programs with different roles (which are all separated, none of these roles must exist in one and the same instance):

- CLIENT
- AUTHENTICATION-SERVER
- AUTHORIZATION-SERVER (there can be a multitude of these)
- RESOURCE-SERVER (also many possible)

And:

I don't want to use any websites a user has to navigate to.

From my studies of OAuth and Open ID Connect I would assume that a Client could get an ID_TOKEN (after authorization) from an AUTHENTICATION-SERVER and could then request ACCESS_TOKENS to different resources from the AUTHORIZATION-SERVERs.

I guess the method I described allows identity theft on the client side.

I cant find a way to easily get id tokens from an authorization server to a client (which I could then use to authenticate to multiple authorization servers). My clients are trusted. I want to use native apps and implement open id connect among them anyway.

I do not want to use any websites as of now and still need to be able to have a secure communication with associations of claims to users and everything. Are OpenID Connect and its possible 'Flows' appropiate for this? Are there any other implementations that would allow the flow I described (or mabye derivations of OpenID Connect)?

Comment: what have you tried? and what problem you got?

Comment: I tried to somehow get an id token from an authentication server to a client but i cant find a way to do it. I also read about people saying you shouldnt do this. But I have a scenario where the client is trusted and this needs to be done to authenticate with different authorization servers.

Comment: I would expect this to work like this: use credentials to obtain id token (using client and authentication server). Then: client uses id token to authenticate with multiple authorization servers. Then: client gets authorization tokens and accesses ressources with them on ressource servers.

Comment: The only examples i can find using (non-webstite!) clients are just api-key accesses using the credentials directly (like the first two identity server quick-start samples)

Comment: It's not recommended but if you really don't want to use a browser (which is somewhat anti-OAuth/OIDC) then ResourceOwnerPassword grant type is the one you'll need to use. This will not return an id_token though, just an access_token.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended but if you really don't want to use a browser (which is somewhat anti-OAuth/OIDC and is full of limitations) then ResourceOwnerPassword grant type is the one you'll need to use. This will not return an id_token though, just an access_token.

id_tokens exist to support front-channel browser-based sign in flows, they serve no purpose if using the ROP grant type.

Access tokens are issued by the authentication/secure token service (IDS4 in this case) and grant the *client* (optionally with user consent) access to the resource. The resource then has its own authorization rules to enforce scope and user-related ACL/business rule access controls.